# Google App Engine not deploying new web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp

I'm currently building a project using Google App Engine, Eclipse, and the Eclipse GAE plugin.  When deploying, I'm noticing the following message:

> ------------ Deploying frontend ------------
>
> Preparing to deploy:  Created staging directory at:
>   'C:\Users\BARMAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3282446993600952313.tmp'
>     Scanning for jsp files.     Compiling jsp files.    Scanning files on
>   local disk.   Initiating update.  Cloning 4 static files.     Cloning 72
>   application files.
>
> Deploying:    Uploading 2 files.  Uploaded 1 files.   Uploaded 2 files.
>     Initializing precompilation...  Sending batch containing 2 file(s)
>   totaling 4KB.     Deploying new version.  Closing update: new version is
>   ready to start serving.   Uploading index definitions.
>
> Deployment completed successfully

After checking my live app (xxxx.appspot.com), my changed servlet mappings (which work locally when running the local dev server) don't appear to have made it.  I'm guessing my web.xml is not being pushed.  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong -- I've tried changing project id, versions, everything, to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you deploying againts the default version? if not, you would need to reach the non-default version via its unique url such as http://version_id-dot-latest-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that my web.xml was malformed.  It seems like there's a bit of inconsistency when dealing with paths in servlet mappings: where `/somepage.jsp` worked locally, it needed to be `somepage.jsp` when it was actually deployed to the live environment.